# replacing a character in a string in python

Tags: python

I am trying to replace a character in a string using python. I am using a function called find_chr to find the location of the character that needs to be replaced.

```
def main():
    s='IS GOING GO'
    x='N'
    y='a'

    rep_chr(s,x,y)
def find_chr(s,char):
    i=0
    for ch in s:
        if ch==char:
            return (i)
            break        
        i+=1
    return -1
def rep_chr(s1,s2,s3):
    return print(s1==s1[0:find_chr(s1,s2)]+s3+s1[(find_chr(s1,s2)+1):])


main()
```

My problem is that instead of getting the new string, the function is returning 'False'. I would appreciate any pointer to get the replaced string.

Comment: Looks like you changed `print(rep_chr(s,x,y))` to `(rep_chr(s,x,y))`...

Comment: Why are you not using `str.replace`? Just trying to recreate it for fun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
return print(s1==s1[0:find_chr(s1,s2)]+s3+s1[(find_chr(s1,s2)+1):])
```

to

```
return s1[0:find_chr(s1,s2)]+s3+s1[(find_chr(s1,s2)+1):]
```

and print the result in your `main`:

```
print(rep_chr(s,x,y))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an inbuilt function:

`string.replace(old, new, count)`

this returns a modified copy

count is optional and is the number of times to replace - if it is set to 2 it will replace the first two occurrences.

`string = 'abc abc abc def'`
`string.replace('abc','xyz',2)`

returns

`'xyz xyz abc def'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `print` statement inside `rep_chr` function.

```
s1==s1[0:find_chr(s1,s2)]+s3+s1[(find_chr(s1,s2)+1):]
```

The above statement means is `s1` equal to `s1[0:find_chr(s1,s2)]+s3+s1[(find_chr(s1,s2)+1):]`? 
which is false and that's why you are getting False as output.